# Возврат данных вызова XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Приветствую,
пытаюсь написать небольшое погодное приложение в процессе обучения.
Для получения данных о текущем местоположении используется [ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io/) 
Написал функцию, которая, по моему мнению, должна отдавать необходимые данные:

```
var getLocationInfo = function() {
    var data = {},
    url = "http://ipinfo.io/json",
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200)
                data.currentLocation = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            else
                console.log("Error location data");
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
    return data;
};
```

К сожалению не хватает знаний понять, как "вытщить" конкретные значения из всего набора возвращаемых данных (нужно значение "City") для передачи их в следующую функцию, которая "пойдет" за погодой.

Благодарю за вашу помощь

Comment: ну data.currentLocation.city, в чем проблема то?

Comment: и плюсом, получение City зависит от того, что получилось после `JSON.parse(req.responseText)`. В данном случае хватит `.city`

Comment: Thanks guys for your help